# Phonegap Local notification doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm currently trying to use [this plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

My problem was I did all the step by step instructions I got from Google but none of them works.

Is there something wrong with this steps:

- install plugin using CLI
- tried the one of the simplest sample I placed it on index.html inside

code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.plugin.notification.local.add({ message: 'Great app!' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same plugin, last I checked there was no ".add" method. Try ".schedule"

Try:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
title: "New Message",
message: "Hi, are you ready? We are waiting.",
sound: "file://sounds/message.mp3",
icon: "http://my.domain.de/avatar/user#id=123"
});
```

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling

Answer (score 0):

I am using this plugin and it works fine. You could try:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: "Customer Calling",
    icon: "http://b2bvn.nsbg.foxconn.com:8080/taxi/call.png",
    text: "You have a registration from customer"
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, where should i put that code?  is it inside index.html then inside function onDeviceReady() {}  ?  or in index.js? i have tried alreay still doesn't work

Comment: I called it in `index.js`. I use `Jquery`, and I put it in: `$(document).ready(function(){});` or in which function you want. Follow [this sample](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples) for more information. Hope this help ^^

Comment: by i've tried it just now as usual it did not work. why is it too difficult to use unlike using vibration and notification plugin and other plugin?

Comment: ^^ Could you please show what have you tried in your question?

Comment: currently i have a very simple example                                                                             inside this `function onDeviceReady() {}`    i have this code `navigator.notification.alert(``"You are the winner!",`alertDismissed,`  `'Game Over',` ` 'Done' ` `); `

Comment: `navigator.notification` works when application displayed on screen. and `local plugin` works also in background. And it only work when you press Home, if you press Back, application will exit and plugin would not play.

Comment: it will work also in phonegap app? im using this now for testing or i need to build it first  @Mr Neo

Comment: Yes, it works also in phonegap application. You need to build application. In my opinion, it doesn't work with testing because it's 3rd party Plugin

Comment: wow now its working!! haha. i tested it using bluestack emulator.wow can't believe it!  thanks  @Mr Neo   so thankful to you

Comment: You're welcome ^^. All 3rd party plugin need to build to use.